# remove_filter excerpt_more from a plugin class

Tags: filters

I'm trying to remove a filter from within my plugin class. I need to remove the 'continue reading' link from the_excerpt. The base theme is the twenty ten theme and they are applying a filter `twentyten_auto_excerpt_more`. I cannot remove the filter, I assume because I'm within a class:

```
class MyAwesomeClass {

private static $instance;

public static function instance() {
    if ( !isset( self::$instance ) ) {
        self::$instance = new MyAwesomeClass;
        self::$instance->setup_actions_and_filters();
    }
    return self::$instance;
}

private function __construct() {}

public function setup_actions_and_filters() {
    add_filter( 'excerpt_more', array( $this, 'change_excerpt_more' ) );
}

public function change_excerpt_more( $excerpt ) {
    remove_filter( 'excerpt_more', 'twentyten_auto_excerpt_more' );
    return '';
}

}

MyAwesomeClass::instance();
```

The filter I am trying to remove:

```
add_filter( 'excerpt_more', 'twentyten_auto_excerpt_more' );
```

Is there a way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that it was `get_the_excerpt` filter that needed removing, in either case it has to be done through `after_setup_theme`:

```
public function setup_actions_and_filters() {
    add_action( 'after_setup_theme', array( $this, 'run_plugin_setup' ) );
}

public function run_plugin_setup() {
    remove_all_filters( 'get_the_excerpt' );
}
```

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

[The priority value has to match on `remove_filter`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_filter). I am guessing that it does not. Try:

```
remove_filter( 'excerpt_more', 'twentyten_auto_excerpt_more' );
```

Or find `add_filter( 'excerpt_more', 'twentyten_auto_excerpt_more'` and check the priority, then make it match.

Comment: There is no priority set, I've removed mine but it still doesn't work and a continue reading link appears...